# Add an actionbar to tabbed layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-support-library

I tried to add to my application, developed with version 2.3 of Android (tabhost) an action bar (via appcompat v7 lib, not a navigation bar...but an action bar), and failed. Can anyone help me in this task?
I also tried to change the tabactivity with fragment (support lib v4) but again no results.

my main activity

```
public class ProjectActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {

private TabHost mTabHost;
private HashMap mapTabInfo = new HashMap();
private TabInfo mLastTab = null;

private class TabInfo {
     private String tag;
     private Class clss;
     private Bundle args;
     private Fragment fragment;
     TabInfo(String tag, Class clazz, Bundle args) {
         this.tag = tag;
         this.clss = clazz;
         this.args = args;
     }

}

class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

    private final Context mContext;

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public TabFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /** (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory#createTabContent(java.lang.String)
     */
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        return v;
    }

}
/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Step 1: Inflate layout
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_project);
    // Step 2: Setup TabHost
    initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
    }
}

/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
 */
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); //save the tab selected
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

/**
 * Step 2: Setup TabHost
 */
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    ProjectActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("tab1"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("tab1", tab1Activity.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    ProjectActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("tab2"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("tab2", tab2Activity.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    ProjectActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("tab3"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("tab3", tab3Activity.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    ProjectActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("tab4"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("tab4", tab4Activity.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    // Default to first tab
    this.onTabChanged("tab1");
    //
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}

/**
 * @param activity
 * @param tabHost
 * @param tabSpec
 * @param clss
 * @param args
 */
private static void addTab(ProjectActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
    // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
    String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

    // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
    // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
    // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
    tabInfo.fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (tabInfo.fragment != null && !tabInfo.fragment.isDetached()) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(tabInfo.fragment);
        ft.commit();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }

    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener#onTabChanged(java.lang.String)
 */
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    TabInfo newTab = (TabInfo) this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    if (mLastTab != newTab) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (mLastTab != null) {
            if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
            }
        }
        if (newTab != null) {
            if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                        newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
            } else {
                ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
            }
        }

        mLastTab = newTab;

        ft.commit();
        this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
}
```

my fragment

```
public class tab1Activity extends Fragment {
/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
 */
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {

        return null;
    }

    return (ScrollView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dimensions, container, false);
}
}
```

Comment: ActionBarSherlock perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using actionbar sherlock, as suggested by KickingLettuce.